# How to Reorder Elements Vertically Glade + Gtk?

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I'm using Glade to design a UI, and I'm struggling to figure out how to reorder elements such that one element is on top of the other vertically. As an example, I added a draw element after a slider, [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtflL.png), but I want to still be able to touch the slider through the draw element. Beyond reordering things manually in the XML/.glade file, how would I move things around such that the draw element gets "drawn" first with the slider on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Die clarification. So far i See from the picture (I dont understand the Text), you create radio buttons and in one type of it, you want to dynamically letting a new window area appearing with a slider in it when clicking?

Comment: So basically I want to be able to, using Glade, reorder the elements in that tree such that the "power_scale_draw" is *above* the thing that says "power_scale" near the top.